# Building a simple responsive grid

Tags: html, css, grid, semantic-ui

I'm fairly new to semantic-ui. This is probably a pretty *stupid* question.

I'm struggling with creating a five column grid layout that is responsive/mobile friendly. Here's a quick image that shows what I am trying to do. Also, *sorry for my sick MS Paint skills*:

Computer:
[image: Computer]

Mobile:

[image: Mobile]

Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outer container is straightforward I think. For the `Segment` which has 5 items in it, you can use something like:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="ui container">

  <div class="ui one column centered grid">

    <div class="center aligned column" style="background-color: #B0C4DE;">
      Some Row
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <div class="ui stackable five column grid">
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #FFF8DC;">Item 1</div>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #F8F8FF;">Item 2</div>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #FFF8DC;">Item 3</div>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #F8F8FF;">Item 4</div>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #FFF8DC;">Item 5</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column" style="background-color: #E0FFFF;">
      New Row
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

The grid is your friend https://semantic-ui.com/collections/grid.html

Comment: Thank you. I remember that I tried that too but had some issues with the last column. The issue was due to a other outer centered grid. I'll try your suggestion later today and update this post.

Comment: Hey, take a look at this: https://plnkr.co/edit/8uWGjfh5tmhwovfenfXj 
It does not work in a nested grid :(

Comment: @hansmeyer I edited the answer and did a fiddle. Please see if it meets your requirements

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot one of the best part on Semantic UI.

https://semantic-ui.com/views/item.html

> Responsive Element
>   Item views are designed to be responsive with images stacking at mobile resolutions.

You just have to put your item elements on a ui items, and it's will works. 
Looks here :

```
<div class="ui items">
     <div class="item">
     <div class="item">
     <div class="item">
     <div class="item">
     <div class="item">
</div>
```

Using grids is cool, but you already have responsive element :)

Peace

Answer (score 0):

I have an "index.html" and a "style.css" to accomplish this.
The html looks like this (call it "index.html"):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="grid example for StackOverflow">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>  Grid Example - by Rob Blansett.
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="Container">
             <p>Container: Content should be horizontally centered.</p>
             <div class="Row" id="One">
                Row #1
             </div>
             <div class="Row" id="Two">
                Row #2
                 <div class="Segment">
                    <div class="SegmentText">
                        Segment
                    </div>
                    <div class="Item" id="Item1">
                         Item #1
                    </div>
                    <div class="Item" id="Item2">
                         Item #2
                    </div>
                    <div class="Item" id="Item3">
                         Item #3
                    </div>
                    <div class="Item" id="Item4">
                         Item #4
                    </div>
                    <div class="Item" id="Item5">
                         Item #5
                    </div>
                 </div>

             </div>
             <div class="Row" id="etc">
                Row ...
             </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the "style.css" looks like this:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

div {
    display: block;
    padding: 1em; 
    margin: 1em;
    border-style: solid;
    position: relative;
}

div.Container {
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 2%
}

div.Row {
    background-color: grey;
}

div.Segment {
    background-color: lightgrey;
}

div.SegmentText {
    border-style: none;
} 

div.Item {
    background-color: darkgray;
}

/* If at least 500 pixels width is available then: */
@media (min-width:500px) {
    div {
        display: grid;
        grid-gap: 1em;
        padding: 1em; 
        margin: 0;
        border-style: solid;
        position: relative;
    }

    div.Container {
        margin-left: 10%;
        margin-right: 10%
    }

    div.Segment {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1Fr 1Fr 1Fr;
    }

    div.SegmentText {
        grid-column: 1 / 4;
        border-style: none;
    } 
}

/* If at least 800 pixels width is available then: */
@media (min-width:800px) {
    div {
        display: grid;
        grid-gap: 1em;
        padding: 1em; 
        margin: 0;
        border-style: solid;
        position: relative;
    }

    div.Container {
        margin-left: 20%;
        margin-right: 20%
    }

    div.Segment {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1Fr 1Fr 1Fr 1Fr 1Fr;
    }

    div.SegmentText {
        grid-column: 1 / 6; 
        border-style: none;
    } 
}
```

Note that I've included @media queries for the window width.  The default style set up is at the top of the CSS, then below that are the query sections that do the GRID stuff if there is a wide-enough window.  So, it will be the one column if less than 500 pixels are available, and it will be 5 columns if at least 800 pixels are available.  I included an intermediate size with 3 columns - just for fun.  Re-size the window and see the adjustment between styles in action.

Here's link to working a copy: 
http://technifusion.com/projects/web/grid-example-01.html

This just gives an idea of how it can be done.

Note: This solution does not use semantic-ui (that the original poster asked for) but this solution may still help people who are not using that framework.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. But I want to ud semantic ui. Don't get me wrong, your code will probably work, but the idea behind a framework is that I don't have to deal with all of this custom CSS. Anyway - thanks for your suggestion, I'll definitely try this later today!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I was ignorant of the semantic ui, so I assumed (incorrectly) that it wasn't required for your use.  I understand now though.

Answer (score 0):

I know you want to use semantic-ui but if you don't mind, you create your layout with bootstrap4 too.

**[Bootstrap4](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/)** methodology is mobile first, so create your html structure to adapt mobile and then grow from there.

Bootstrap use a grid system based on rows of 12 columns. You define the space taken for each column using the class *col-x* for mobile, *col-md-x* for medium width window, *col-lg-x* for large. "x" defines the number of columns (x<=12) taken by the *div* element. Check the [Bootstrap4 documentation](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/introduction/).

Remember to add the related js libraries and css to your html file.

Check this snippet:

```css
#row-1{
  background-color: orange;
}
#row-2{
  background-color: yellow;
}
#row-3{
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/tether@1.2.4/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div id="row-1" class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      Row #1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="row-2" class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-2">
      Item 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-2">
      Item 2
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-2">
      Item 3
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-2">
      Item 4
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-2">
      Item 5
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-2">
      Item 6
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="row-3" class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      Row #3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Maybe this will help somebody in the future who uses bootstrap! :)

Comment: @hansmeyer the title of your question is **Building a simple responsive grid**, so it will be read by people wanting to build a simple responsive grid, no matter what they are using, because you did not specify semantic-ui in it. Feel bad for the down vote :(.

Comment: I'm sorry for not including semantic-ui. I haven't downvoted you though. I'll upvote your answer to make that clear.